# ¿ Cómo puedo llenar un JtextField, seleccionando una opción del JcomboBox? EclipseIDE

Tags: string, combobox, jtextfield, double

Estoy trabajando en *ECLIPSE IDE* y estoy tratando de que al seleccionar un item del combobox me arroje la información en el *Jtextfield* de cuyo item.

Ejemplo : Ítems : Radio , Televisor , celular

- Selecciono el item Radio (combobox)
  Y en el *Jtextfield* debe aparecer la información:

  - Precio : 10.00 *(Jtextfield)*
  - Cantidad : 2 *(Jtextfield)*
  - Marca : Lenovo *(Jtextfield)*

Answer (score 0):

Dentro del actionLister-Performed del comboBox, mediante `.getSelectedItem()` obtendrás el valor del comboBox.  Ahora, con `.equals(x)`, preguntarás si el valor obtenido del comboBox es igual a x, si es el caso, mediante `.setText()` pondrás los datos que quieres que el textField contenga.

```
  JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
        comboBox.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Radio")) {

                    textField.setText(10.0 + " " + 2.0 + " Lenovo");

                }else if (comboBox.getSelectedItem().equals("Televisor")) {

                    textField.setText("DATOS AQUÍ");

                }
            }
        });
        comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Radio", "Televisor", "Opcion 3" }));
        comboBox.setBounds(94, 70, 93, 22);
        frame.getContentPane().add(comboBox);
```

Comment: Gracias , me ayudó mucho :).